# Finding the nth Fibonacci number for n as big as 10^19

Tags: python, fibonacci

I need to make a program to find the nth Fibonacci number and here is my code:

```
fib,num2 = 0,1
for i in range(int(input())):
    fib,num2 = num2,fib+num2
print(fib)
```

Some of the cases my program needs to do in less than 2 seconds are as big as 10^19.

How would I code that?

Comment: the best solution to fibonacci is O(1)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, i am not sure but you can try memoization

```
var fib3 = (function(){
    var memo = {};
    return function(n) {
        if (memo[n]) {return memo[n];}
        return memo[n] = (n <= 2) ? 1 : fib3(n-2) + fib3(n-1);
    };
})();
```